# how to add unit test to existing target which be launched by another process in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unit-testing, cocoa

I have a xcode project which has two targets(app),one is UI(main) process, the other is Service process, the UI process launch the Service process.Now I want to add unit test to the Service target which to be built in UI target app/Contents/Resource path(As is shown in picture).when I run test(command+U) the Service target, the main app run but the unit test for the service app never run and always with "Testing". how should I add unit test for the service target?

Comment: It will appear error:"Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" when run test

Comment: when run test, It will appear "Bundle injected into....but CInjectBundleInto environment variable set to...", the two path are different, I try to make the two path same, but no effect